# How much ads is too much?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, advertisement

Every app/website owner that relies on Ads to monetize wishes to fill up the entire page with ads to become rich in two days.

The question is are there some well known frameworks or studies that guide through best practices for amount of ads that can be placed before the user destroys the heck out of the machine?

Please keep in mind, i am not looking for answers like "research it, or benchmark it", i'm trying to find somewhat a golden rule of thumb for cases where resources lack to conduct such activities, even if it comes slightly at the cost of accuracy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with advertisements is that they are units of content that are *especially designed to take focus away from other content*. Even one advert will already be competing with the content you actually want to present to the users. Multiple adverts will be competing with each other and could make your page feel like a battleground, which is very off putting for users who are on the page to read your content.

One strategy that works well (in mobile devices at least) is the advert that only appears half way through the content. It briefly displaces your content, and the user can scroll past it and get back to the second half of the content. This separation still shows the adverts, but avoids individual adverts competing with each other, and with your content.

If there is really a lot of content (like a very long in depth news article), you might get away with doing this scrolling advert more than once, but remember that the content will get devalued if the ratio of adverts to content is too high. The type of advert will also affect the perception of your content (seedy looking advertisements will be less tolerable than ones for luxury watches).

Comment: thank you @Franchesca  you tend to provide an interesting and valuable perspective in your answers

Answer (score 4):

The first Ad is already too much.

But you can get creative and use an intrusive ad, that will track your profile on facebook and that will be ideally positionned to prevent user from accessing key functionalities.

Do not forget to add a way to close this ad, for example a very small 'x' button, that would be impossible to click on mobile devices, triggering the ad instead.

Of course you can get more creative, there's no limit to evil power.

If you want more dark patterns you can find a lot more on the internet

Sincerely yours, Satan (let's get in touch)

Comment: I have no clue how to respond to this lol

Comment: I agree with more creative ways of using the advertisements, but using dark patterns is just going to result in poor user experience in the long term anyway, which could be worse than the ad itself :p